# Develop DAG that will parallel upload chunks of huge csv file to Database

Tags: airflow

I want to develop DAG that will parallel upload chunks of huge csv file to Clickhouse, so if any advice how to do it?

Is this the best way, or there is another way to do it?

Right now I have a prototype of DAG, that create chunks from csv based on lines count and dynamically generate DAGs task. (so each time generate different task count that depends on csv file size)

```py
def generate_chunks(*args, **kwargs):
    with open(kwargs['file_path'], 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)

        # TODO: chunk size from Variables
        chunks = list(gen_chunks(reader, chunk_size=10000))
        chunks_count = len(chunks)

        # TODO: variable name from main_dag_id
        os.system(f'airflow variables --set WebsiteStatisticsChunks {chunks_count}')

        for i in range(chunks_count):
            reset_tasks_status('chunks_' + str(i), str(kwargs['execution_date']))

        return chunks
```

```py
    WebsiteStatisticsChunks = Variable.get("WebsiteStatisticsChunks")
    logging.info("The current WebsiteStatisticsChunks value is " + str(WebsiteStatisticsChunks))

    for index in range(int(WebsiteStatisticsChunks)):
        dynamicTask = PythonOperator(
            task_id='chunks_' + str(index),
            dag=dag,
            provide_context=True,
            python_callable=do_some_work,
            op_args=['chunks', index],
            op_kwargs={

                'chunks': "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='create_chunks') }}",
                'file_path': "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='extract_cards_plugin') }}",
                'clickhouse_conn_id': 'clickhouse_test',
                'database': 'dev_test',
                'table': 'pg_raw_cms_cards',
            },
        )
        create_chunks.set_downstream(dynamicTask)
        dynamicTask.set_downstream(ending_task)
```

Comment: I've been doing something similar for a while and I've found this technique to work just fine